# Como desconsiderar chaves dentro de uma String formatada em python

Tags: python

Olá, essa é minha primeira pergunta por aqui, eu tenho uma string e nela eu preciso por um valor aleatório, porém, ao torná-la formatada, outras chaves dentro passam a ser um placeholder, mas não é isso que eu quero.Trata-se desse código: A string trata-se de uma function do java script, e nela há chaves, há como eu "**desconsiderar essa chaves**" na string formata?

```
import random
number = random.randint(280, 320)
func = f"""
function saveToLocalStorage(e) {
    var t = localStorage.getItem("readData2") || "[]",
        t = JSON.parse(t),
        n = {
            slug: e["viewed_book[book_slug]"],
            percentage: e["viewed_book[percentage]"],
            initial_percentage: e.initial_percentage,
            final_percentage: e.final_percentage,
            resume_element_id: e.resume_element_id,
            resume_doc_id: e.resume_doc_id,
            time_spent: {},
            viewed_book_id: gon.viewed_book,
            words_per_minute: e.words_per_minute,
            token: e.token
        },
        r = t.concat(n);
    localStorage.setItem("readData2", JSON.stringify(r))
}""".
print(func)
```

Comment: Basta escapar as chaves substituindo as `{` por `{{` e `}` por `}}`, mas no seu caso acho que seria melhor simplesmente remover o `f` no começo da string, já que você não está utilizando interpolação mesmo.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado mesmo! O uso de duas chaves me serviu!

Answer (score 0):

Como o @user140828 colocou como comentário:

Basta escapar as chaves substituindo as { por {{ e } por }}.